# How to call a webservice with GET?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have experiences in creating clients to a **SOAP** Webservice using `JAX-WS`. Therefore I'd mainly create a `@WebService` class with `@WebMethod` methods that take `@WebParam` params and return a `@WebResult`.

Mostly I start using  CXF`to auto-generate the Java classes from the`WSDL`.

But what if the webservice is a **GET** service instead of a SOAP, like http://www.cleartrip.com/places/hotels/info/41748.

I can use a XSD accordingly to auto-generate my Java classes to JAXB as well.
But how do I then call that GET-Service?  Which framework will assist me here? Is it also possible with JAX-WS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused because this is a restfull service and not a SOAP web service, java has an API for accessing restful services easily, see 'https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html' for more info.

Answer (score 0):

What you call a `GET` service looks like a RESTful service. Take a look at JAX-RS 2.0 and the new client API.